# How to deal with Window's extra partitions when installing next to Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I'm trying to dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows on a UEFI, GPT partitioned system, starting from an Ubuntu install. I have read that you must simply create some empty space (which I have done), and then run the Windows installer and point it to that empty space.

This ends up creating more than one partition, which is annoying, considering I may want to resize the partitions later on, and I'm not sure if the System Reserved Partition is safe to move. If it's safe to move, then I may proceed with this method and just move that partition to the end of the disk.

I have read that creating a partition stops this from happening, but I'm not sure what filesystem should that partition be (NTFS?), or if anything unexpected may happen (could Windows create the partition anyway at the start of the disk and break my Ubuntu?).

Comment: The MSR must be before the first NTFS partition. See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations Often better to install Windows first and let it do its thing. Then shrink Windows with its tools to make unallocated space for Ubuntu. Better still to have separate drives.

Comment: A Windows 10 install creates 4 partitions, and you should not remove any of them. Ubuntu only *needs* two partitions, your `/` partition and the EFI (shared by all OS and you should already have).  If you do not want to create a partition for Ubuntu, you might want to look at running it in a VM, although depending on your hardware and virtualization capability, it may not run as well as "bare metal"